# python3 request.post is failing intermittently

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

We are using python 3.5.1 and requests 2.25. I am using request.post to get a token. It fails when we ran the first time, the same thing when we ran 2nd time it is running successfully. Did anyone face the same issue before?

Comment: That sounds like the endpoint and not `requests` necessarily. Could you provide the endpoint, specifically the `requests.post` command that you use?

Comment: I am using endpoint /redfish/v1/SessionService/Sessions/.

Comment: But what is the full endpoint: https://...

Comment: Full endpoint is:https://10.131.0.6/redfish/v1/SessionService/Sessions/

Comment: We tried to Curl and it  is working fine . curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -d \
'{"UserName":"admin","Password":"HP1nvent"}' \
 'https://10.131.0.6/redfish/v1/SessionService/Sessions/'

Comment: Endpoints can go non-responsive every so often. That's not a surprise. If it works consistently then it's not your API POST, it's how reliable the web API is

Comment: If it is non-responsive, the response should fail every time. But it is consistently failing alternatively.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it is due to dependency packages. When we downgraded the below packages, it started to work

> **Previous Packages which are not working:** cachetools==4.2.1 google-auth==1.27.0 pytz==2021.1 rsa==4.5
>
> **Working packages** cachetools==4.2.0 rsa==4.6 pytz==2020.4 google-auth==1.23.0